# Android Testing: how to click on dialog box's button?

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator, junit, robotium

Using Junit, I can click on “Set Time” button (as shown on the figure 1). Then it will open a new dialog box as shown in the Figure 2 (at the end). Can you please tell me how I can click the “Done” button on the newly opened dialog box? If you can show me an example, I would grately appreciate it.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I will post the answer later on. thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

if you use AlertDialog , you must use this method :

```
.setPositiveButton("Done",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            })             )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what if we have "Dialog" instead of "AlertDialog"? Are these both same? Can you please give small example? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In that case perhaps the best option is to use [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) of if you prefer to write your tests in Java you can use the `chimpchat` library. It use is described in [Using monkey from Java](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-using-monkey-from-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

In API >= 15, [`callOnClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#callOnClick()), else [`performClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick())

```
dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button1).callOnClick();
```